# Dockerfile not installing ggmap

Tags: r, git, docker, dockerfile

I'm getting errors when I'm trying to run a project through a docker container. The image fails and says that ggmap was not installed, despite it being called in the Dockerfile.

Here's a link to my repository: https://github.com/TedHaley/tree_value.git

This is what my dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM rocker/tidyverse
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('devtools')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('ezknitr')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('lubridate')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('dplyr')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('readr')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('ggplot2')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('rgdal')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('broom')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('maptools')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('gpclib')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('packrat')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('MASS')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('scales')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('stringr')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('hexbin')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('reshape2')"

RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('ggmap', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
```

It'd be a huge help if anyone has any ideas as to why `ggmap` is not installedi correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your image is based on [`rocker/tidyverse`](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/tidyverse/~/dockerfile/), itself based on [`rocker/rstudio`](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/blob/master/rstudio/Dockerfile), based on [rocker/-base](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/blob/master/r-base/Dockerfile).
None of them have ggmap installed.

See for instance [`achubaty/r-spatial-devel`](https://hub.docker.com/r/achubaty/r-spatial-devel/~/dockerfile/), which does in

```
## install R spatial packages && cleanup 
RUN xvfb-run -a install.r \ 
                geoR \ 
                ggmap \
```

Try starting from an image where you can test that `ggmap` is present.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a total Docker noob. So the link you pointed me to had used a linux repository as the base image. How can I link multiple images within the same file? I'm guessing I can't say 'FROM' multiple times?

Comment: @TeddyHaley No you can start with FROM that image, and add  (copy) lines from the rocker image. Or you can start FROM the rocker image, by add what is missing, copying it from the achuabaty image.

Comment: @TeddyHaley But even all that, the point was: try a `docker run --rm -it anImage bash`, and inside that shell session, check ggmap is available and working.

Comment: FROM rocker/tidyverse

RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('devtools')"

RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('ezknitr')"

RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('lubridate')"

RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('dplyr')"

RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('readr')"

RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('ggplot2')"

RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('broom')"

RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('gpclib')"

RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('packrat')"

RUN xvfb-run -a install.r \ 
                ggmap \
       maptools \
        rgdal \

Comment: ^So I'm not sure I entirely follow... The thing I did above does not work (obviously). Any tutorials you can recommend?

Comment: @TeddyHaley Again, my point is: way before trying to install anything, take an image where ggmap is supposed to be already installed, and test that. Then start adding stuff.

Comment: @TeddyHaley As for tutorials, you have https://docs.docker.com/get-started/, http://play-with-docker.com/ and https://www.katacoda.com/courses/docker